# Clojure - remove 0 from an Array of bytes?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm reading file into a byte array, however the byte array has some trailing 0s which I would like to remove (return new byte array without the 0s). But byte array is not a listish thing so I cannot use filter/remove/map on it.

Is the only solution to use recursion over the byte array?

Thanks!

Comment: i found it... i didn't realize that the tick is not for decoration. thanks

Comment: A general note.. in Clojure there are `seq`s and then there are `seqable` things. Java arrays are `seqable` so `(seq a)` returns a `seq` backed by `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use sequence operations on byte arrays:

```
(byte-array (take-while pos? (.getBytes (slurp "some/binary/file.dat"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A byte array in Clojure is a sequence, and filter, map, and other functions work on sequences.

You can use this function to remove trailing zeroes:

```
(defn pos-byte-arrayE
    [seq]
    (take-while pos? seq))
```

You can use filter on your byte array to remove all zeros.

```
(defn pos-byte-arrayF
    [seq]
    (filter pos? seq))

repl-test.core=> (pos-byte-arrayF [1 2 3 0])
(1 2 3)
```